# How to hide a menu item for a certain language in joomla?

Tags: joomla1.5, menuitem, joomfish

I have multilingual website in joomla and want to hide one menu item (not all the menu items, but just one of them) for a certain languages, for instance, when current language is English  hide menu item.

How can I achieve this? I am using joomfish with joomla 1.5 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set condition in the component and module which displays menu

u would need to hard code it

for example for language with id = 60

conditions like in php

```
if( $lid == 60) {

// show the menu for a speacial language

}

else{

 //  else show the basic menu for all


 }
```

refer this link http://www.packtpub.com/article/customizing-menus-menu-in-joomla

Comment: Could you go more deep and clarify how to hide an item with id=60 lets say. Thank you.

Comment: I want to hide menu item id=60 when lanaguage='english' for example.

Comment: i a have did this for links in joomla  . but i had restricted links according to user group like admin , manager or user . this will work . just try where the code is for showing menus

Comment: I don't understand why do it like this, 3.0 and this is built right in to the back end - and 1.5 is now unsupported