# Different link for a menu item in another language

Tags: menu, joomla1.5, multilingual

I have a menu item in a Joomla 1.5 site that needs to have a certain link when it's in Greek (default language) and another link when it's in English.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681962/how-to-hide-a-menu-item-for-a-certain-language-in-joomla) which maybe gives me a hint, but I would need more detailed help. I don't even know in which files I'd need to insert the code. How do I find out what's the language id?

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate it, I know in 3.0 and I think right back to at least 1.5 in the Menu item you can select which language the link appears for. So you have two link items, one which displays for English viewers and one for Greek.

Ps why are you still using 1.5, it is now officially unsupported, I strongly suggest you move up to at least 2.5 [Joomla 1.5 end of life](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_and_Migrating_Joomla)

Comment: I'm using Joomla 1.5 because it's an old site, made five years ago, and now the owners just wanted to add another language.

I just checked the menu options, it appears it's impossible to assign a menu item to a certain language.

I have also tried to edit the link of the translation, but the link is uneditable.

Comment: I still haven't resolved this issue, so any help would be appreciated. I think I need to edit the default.php file for the mod_mainmenu, but how do I find out the language id for the language I want to associate content with?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know are you use SEF on your site... But using JoomFish for multylanguage it very simple to make different links for the same menu item for different languages. Just make translation for menu item you need and enter different alias for this. For example you have a link `www.mysite.com/gk/contacts`. When you'll translate menu item `Contacts` on English and enter alias `conatact-us` you'll get a link like this: `mysite.com/en/contact-us`. I hope it will be helpfull for you.